# Плавный слайдер

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

Как можно сделать плавную замену слайдов? ([пример](http://lol-game.ru/) слайдера на главной странице).

Какие параметры в css или действия в js отвечают за это? Интересует только эта часть слайдера.

Если здесь участвует javaScript,то попрошу уточнить это (и, тем более, если jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Эффект называется «карусель». Есть огромное количество реализаций, в т.ч. [плагины к jQuery](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/).

Не сложно сделать свой вариант, в т.ч. на чистом JS.

По событию для смены слайда (нажатию на кнопку, стрелку на клавиатуре, таймеру, ещё какому-то) надо, чтобы текущий слайд «уехал», а новый – «приехал».

Движение можно сделать двумя способами:

- меняя часто-часто JS'ом положение картинки;
- или CSS3 transitions – просто дать двум слайдам новое положение сразу, а анимация выполнится за счёт CSS3 инструкций. Пример:

```js
var state = true,
    box = document.getElementById("box");
document.getElementById("tggl").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(state=!state) {
    box.className = "";
  } else {
    box.className = "right";
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

.right {
  width: 90px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  transform: translate(500px,0px) rotate(3deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>

<button type="button" id="tggl">Нажми меня</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,а такой вопрос,смогу ли я это легко реализовать на чистом javaScript?Или придётся писать кучу кода?

Comment: добавил в ответ.

Comment: Я понял как это сделать,но есть ещё один небольшой вопрос как вы посоветуете сделать это "валидно"?Через какое позиционирование?Или это не имеет значение лишь бы мне было удобно,что в таком случае на счёт кросбраузерности?
Я имею ввиду ваш первый вариант с JS.

Comment: «валидно» – взять готовый плагин с репутацией и обновляемый.